# Why is Wordpress wrapping my post images in a dvi with fixed width?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wysiwyg

I have developed probably 15-18 custom sites using Wordpress as my CMS and have never seen this before.  Every time I insert an image (from the media gallery or directly into the WYSIWYG) it wraps that image in a div with id=attachment-[att#]. It also gives that div a fixed width which is causing quite the headache when trying to make my images responsive.  Does anyone know how to stop this, I have been trying for a few hours. Thanks! Oh btw, I am using a custom theme with minimal markup, just a simple blog archive and single page and a frontpage, the only thing I have done in my functions.php is to enqueue my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this was a new feature back in 2015 when this was asked. The answer is that when a caption is set on an image in a post (rather than just an uncaptioned image) the editor wraps it in the `[caption]` shortcode. That shortcode can be filtered (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/img_caption_shortcode/) but the width attribute always has to be a pixel dimension width greater than 0 and without that attribute the caption will not render (in that case just the image will be shown).

The markup for the captioned image depends on if your theme supports HTML5 markup for the caption. When developing your own theme you may or may not want to enable this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference%2Ffunctions%2Fadd_theme_support%2F/

My working solution is to force the width to 100% with a CSS override on the caption class: `.wp-caption {width: 100% !important}`